# Set Use value application.properties from another properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building a spring boot application, can application.properties value get from another property

I have an application.properties like this

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/test
org.quartz.dataSource.qDS.URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCL
```

can Spring boot doing like this ?

```
db.connections.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/test
spring.datasource.url= db.connections.url
org.quartz.dataSource.qDS.URL=db.connections.url
```

Comment: you mean other property value or oher property file?

Comment: No, but in a same property file. but if it's not possible, it's okay to read from another file, as long as it's not configured in the java class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring properties that depend on other properties can be defined like below in your Class:

```
@Value("#{myFile:${myProperties}/myfile.txt}")
private String myFileName;
```

Spring can combine properties

```
myDir=/path/to/mydir
```

myFile=${myDir}/myfile.txt

Properties file :

```
myDir=/path/to/mydir
```

Answer (score 3):

I've solved with adding ${...}  to set value from other property

this is how I solved :

```
app.dbconnectionstring=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCL

#spring default datasource
spring.datasource.url=${db.dbconnectionstring}

#quartz datasource
org.quartz.dataSource.qDS.URL=${app.dbconnectionstring}
```

Comment: Cool! I got late by 23 seconds. But glad that you got the solution.

Comment: That is the right way. More robust (no file name depending) and more readable.